# Passing simple pointer as double pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers

I have to write a program that multiplies two vectors for my coding class and the argument types of the implemented functions are set by our teacher.

I can not figure out how to pass the vectors, which are one dimensional arrays, as double pointers to one of the implemented functions.

I have tried to use the address-operator, since I want to point to the address of the beginning of the array, where the function is supposed to reserve memory space for the array. But the compiler always tells me

```
incompatible pointer type, expected int **
```

and it does not work without any operator either.

```c
//all functions set by worksheet
int array_create(int **v, int n);//function with double pointer argument
void array_init(int *v, int n);
int mult_array(int *x, int *y, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    int x[10];
    int y[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    array_create(x, 7); // see here
    array_create(y, 7); // see here
    array_init(x, 7);
    array_init(y, 7);
    printf("\nResult: %i", mult_array(x, y, 7));
    array_destroy(x);
    array_destroy(y);
    return 0;
}

int array_create(int **v, int n)
{

    v = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(!v){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

visibly the goal of `array_create` is to allocate and save the address in the first parameter, so change it to be :

```
int array_create(int **v, int n)   
{
  *v = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  if(!*v){
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

you need to call is in the right way :

```
int * x;
int * y;
srand(time(NULL));
array_create(&x, 7);
array_create(&y, 7);
```

*x* and *y* now contains the addresses of the allocated memory blocks (supposing there are enough memory). while `array_create` return 0 or 1 it can be a good idea to test the returned value ;-).

Comment: yes yes, "the addresses of the allocated memory blocks" sorry for the missing word and my bad english, you are right to warn me

Comment: In C we need to be picky! ;-)

Comment: @alk not only in C héhé, you are hard with me, I had to use google translation to understand "picky" :-)

Comment: Mon francais est justment tros, tros mauvais, excuse ... ;-)

Comment: That works, thank you! Tried different combinations of vector and pointer notation, but not like this, thanks!

Comment: @Link: You might like to read about how arrays and pointers relate, ... or just don't.

Comment: I have actually(thank you, Kernighan ;)) and the other programs of the worksheet (also related to pointers) worked just fine, just in this case I got confused somehow, because I thought the adress-operator would work...so you're right, I have some more reading up to do!

Comment: @Link look also at the tool _valgrind_ if it is available on your host, it is one of the magic tools you will be happy to use

Comment: @alk Thanks for the tip!